# Subtracting characters in a back reference from a character class in java.util.regex.Pattern

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to subtract the characters in a Java regex back reference from a character class?

e.g., I want to use `String#matches(regex)` to match either:

1. any group of characters that are `[a-z']` that are enclosed by `"`

   Matches: "abc'abc"

   Doesn't match: "1abc'abc"

   Doesn't match: 'abc"abc'
2. any group of characters that are `[a-z"]` that are enclosed by `'`

   Matches: 'abc"abc'

   Doesn't match: '1abc"abc'

   Doesn't match: "abc'abc"

The following regex won't compile because `[^\1]` isn't supported:

```
(['"])[a-z'"&&[^\1]]*\1
```

Obviously, the following will work:

```
'[a-z"]*'|"[a-z']*"
```

But, this style isn't particularly legible when `a-z` is replaced by a much more complex character class that must be kept the same in each side of the "or" condition.

I know that, in Java, I can just use `String` concatenation like the following:

```
String charClass = "a-z";
String regex     = "'[" + charClass + "\"]*'|\"[" + charClass + "']*\"";
```

But, sometimes, I need to specify the regex in a config file, like XML, or JSON, etc., where java code is not available.

I assume that what I'm asking is almost definitely not possible, but I figured it wouldn't hurt to ask...

Comment: You can't do that in character class. However, you can use a negative look-ahead instead `(?!\1)[a-z']`

Comment: '[a-z"]'|"[a-z']" - I assume you meant to add an asterisk after each character group - i.e., [a-z"]* instead of just [a-z"] which'll match only one character.

Comment: @bjfletcher Thanks for catching my typo.

Comment: even if you think that `'[a-z"]*'|"[a-z']*"` is less readable, it is probably the best way (nothing forbids to use the whitespace mode to make your pattern more readable and to add comments). Something like `(?=["'])(?:'[a-z"]*'|"[a-z']*")` can be very efficient. Trying to factorize (too much) a pattern isn't always a good idea.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte The main thing I was trying to avoid was repeating a much longer character class than `[a-z]` on two sides of an "or".  Say, e.g., the class took 100 characters to specify.  That's why I mentioned using java `String` concatenation, but there are some times when you must specify a regex outside of code (like in XML)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: There is no need for `(?=["'])` at the beginning. I can't think of how it improves the performance. The `'` and `"` at the beginning of each branch already takes care of that.

Comment: @nhahtdh: I'm not sure that java regex engine is smart enough to take the first literal character of each branch of an alternation and to prevent  each character of the string to be tested (for nothing) with the two branches of the alternation.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: It will just test the 2 branches, there is no prefix optimization, though I don't see any point in adding the look-ahead there. There are only 2 alternatives here.

Comment: @nhahtdh: after some tests, it seems that even with only 2 alternatives, adding a lookahead makes the pattern ~2x faster, but I admit that it's only significant for long strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to use a negative look-ahead to make sure that every character in between the quotes is not the quotes:

```
(['"])(?:(?!\1)[a-z'"])*+\1
         ^^^^^^
```

(I also make the quantifier *possessive*, since there is no use for backtracking here)

This approach is, however, rather inefficient, since the pattern will check for the quote character for every single character, on top of checking that the character is one of the allowed character.

The alternative with 2 branches in the question `'[a-z"]*'|"[a-z']*"` is better, since the engine only checks for the quote character once and goes through the rest by checking that the current character is in the character class.

Comment: I always thought that a lookahead had to follow a some other token.  Is `(['"])` the token that `(?!\1)` follows?

Comment: @XDR: I don't quite get your question. Look-ahead asserts that from the current position, you can't find the pattern inside the look-ahead, after the assertion succeeds, you resume matching from before you enter the look-ahead. Therefore, the fragment `(?:(?!\1)[a-z'"])*+` means: before you match the next character, check that it is not the same as the opening quote (which is captured in capturing group 1).

Answer (score 1):

You could use two patterns in one OR-separated pattern, expressing both your cases:

```
//                           | case 1: [a-z'] enclosed by "
//                           |                     | OR
//                           |                     | case 2: [a-z"] enclosed by '
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=\")([a-z']+)(?=\")|(?<=')([a-z\"]+)(?=')");

String[] test = {
        // will match group 1 (for case 1)
        "abcd\"efg'h\"ijkl",
        // will match group 2 (for case 2)
        "abcd'efg\"h'ijkl",
};
for (String t: test) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
        System.out.println(m.group(2));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
efg'h
null
null
efg"h
```

**Note**

There is nothing stopping you from specifying the enclosing characters or the character class itself somewhere else, then building your `Pattern` with components unknown at compile-time.

Something in the lines of:

```
// both strings are emulating unknown-value arguments
String unknownEnclosingCharacter = "\"";
String unknownCharacterClass = "a-z'";
// probably want to catch a PatternSyntaxException here for potential 
// issues with the given arguments
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
    String.format(
        "(?<=%1$s)([%2$s]+)(?=%1$s)", 
        unknownEnclosingCharacter, 
        unknownCharacterClass
    )
);
String[] test = {
        "abcd\"efg'h\"ijkl",
        "abcd'efg\"h'ijkl",
};
for (String t: test) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(t);
    while (m.find()) {
        // note: only main group here
        System.out.println(m.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
efg'h
```

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte let me rephrase my answer :)

Comment: I am trying to avoid the "or" condition.  See `'[a-z"]*'|"[a-z']*"` and the subsequent explanation in my question.

Comment: @XDR:  Note that this approach is interesting if you want to obtain the content between quotes in a same group like this: `["']((?<=\")[a-z']*(?=\")|(?<=')[a-z\"]*(?='))["']`. Using a backreference will only slow down your pattern. See my other comment too.

Comment: @XDR hopefully my edit gives you an additional idea here: i.e. building the ` Pattern` with variable bits.